# How can I perform a Erosion Prevention Project on flat to steep trails?

Tags: erosion-control

I am a Boy Scout and is getting ready to do a conservation project.  I want to help prevent erosion on trails at a local park.  I've been having trouble finding answers on google so came here to ask for help.

Answer (score 2):

Waterbars are a fairly standard trail technique to limit/prevent erosion by preventing water from running down the trail for much dstance, removing it to the side.

And the top link that "should be good" on trail waterbars from the US Government is dead, so here's [one from Vermont](https://dec.vermont.gov/sites/dec/files/wsm/lakes/Lakewise/docs/LP_BMPWaterbars.pdf), instead.It describes a style more suited to roads or driveways, but other than the crushed stone fill it communicates the idea of a foot trail waterbar as well. I'll put that Federal link under "things you should be able to find, but there it isn't."

In very steep terrain they might be steps as well as waterbars. In terrain where steps are not needed, the waterbars (which can be made as a simple ditch, or as a ditch reinforced by stone or timber to resist foot and/or water erosion better) are level with the trail surface, and the water channel in front of them on the uphill side is lower than the trail surface. In some cases two pieces of timber or sets of stones are used to make a channel between them reinforced on both sides.

Foot and/or bicycle erosion tends to wear a depression into the soil, and water follows that - if it goes far enough, the water erodes the ditch further. Apart from waterbars, you can also reshape a section of trail to have a rise (or crown, in road-building terms) in the middle where people walk, and shed water to the sides.

More broadly, I'll make a sound guess that the ATC (Appalachian trail club - whoops, "conservancy" now) also has some guidelines or standards. Unfortunately, the basic ones appear to be "for sale in book form, not available online", but [here's their accessibility guide](https://appalachiantrail.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/increasing-opportunities-for-access-on-the-appalachian-trail-a-design-guide.pdf). Depending where you are, there may be other trail organizations closer to you, with standards and procedures that apply better to your local terrain/conditions.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a conservation authority or city or county organization that is responsible they may have guidelines on what they want used.

Techniques I have seen include:

- using 6' T bars cut in half and small diameter logs  (4" to 6") to stabilize the edges of paths on hills and on slopes.  Place the log parallel to the path and use a sledge hammer with the T Bars to keep the log in place
- for big washouts and boggy areas a raised path can be made.  A boardwalk of lumber is a pretty advanced project but even using 4" to 6" diameter logs laid beside each other will be an improvement
- sometimes even signage can be a great help. Adding trail markers to indicate where to go nudges people in the right direction